# How to prevent tendencies to upper-left corner?

Tags: c++, tilemap

In a 2D tile-based game I'm making, I have a loop that runs through each of the tiles to check and apply values.
One of the effects is intended to make a circle around itself, using a similar method. However, instead of making a circle (or a square, due to the shape of the map), it tends to smear towards the upper left corner.

In have tried running the loop in the reverse direction every other round, but oddly the effect persists.

I am wondering if there are any tips for preventing such a buildup.

edit:
here's the current code of the simulation system
http://pastebin.com/NsgK0SxP

Comment: Are you updating a single matrix or do you have 2; a "now" and "next" matrix. You need two to avoid effects induced by order of comparisons

Comment: it's currently reading and writing one matrix containing the objects for the data of the tiles

Comment: While it will be possible to do it that way it'll be very difficult unless you accept small errors caused by order of operations. For example effects will travel very quickly in the +x and +y directions and very slowly in the other directions

Comment: that seems to be the problem currently

Comment: If you don't want to have 2 matrices  (which can be painful for other reasons) the tiles themselves will need to manage this. Each time step each tile has 2 commands called on it `createNextState` and `commitNextState`. Each tile has `create` called on it then after all tiles are called `commit` is called on each one.  If a tile is asked a question about its state it replies with its **committed** state

Comment: On line 257 I can see you're using newTiles as an input not an output. If for example a tile only has 4 moisture to give it will give 2 to the top left, 2 to top and the zero to everything else. It should  give out the excess randomly if it doesn't have enough for all surrounding tiles

Comment: unfortunately,removing the check doesn't seem to remedy the uneven expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing a distortion because you are asking tiles to the left and top of you a different question to the ones on the bottom right.

To the left and top you are asking "what's your state right now" because they were updated before you whereas you're asking tiles to the bottom right "what was your state one tick ago" because they haven't been updated yet.

This causes effects to travel very fast in the +x and +y directions but slow in the -x and -y directions. Causing your distortion.

To deal with this you have to ask all tiles "what was your state one tick ago". So you need a concept of "last tick" and "this tick" for all your tiles. You can do this many ways, the easiest is to have 2 matrices fulfilling this role. Alternatively this can be managed on the tile level with each tile  having `createNextState` and `commitNextState` methods where the state is only committed after all tiles have had their new state build (and questions to neighbouring tiles are always about the **committed** state)

Comment: now I've tried using 2 matrices and reading from one to write to the other, then equating them before rendering (new is old step) so that all the writes are done on the new frame before the rendering and before the next cycle, but it still seems to do this

Comment: @user Then you may have a logical error, could you include the relevant code in your question

Comment: added code to question

Comment: turns out I wasn't adding value to the right amount of tiles(math error) leaving one side with a 2 tile spread and the other with a 1 tile spread. this answer brought up a valid point in ensuring the tiles would all be written evenly